# Doctrine 2 under Zend error: Class Entities\X has no association named Entities\Y

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, mapping, one-to-one

I have a rather strange problem. I'm using Doctrine 2 under Zend Framework 1.11. I have a database called "Sessions", which are training sessions for students. Each session has an associated note, called a SOAPE note. Edit: I am now including both of the entities in question.

Sessions:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\Sessions")
 * @Table(name="Sessions")
 */

 class Sessions
{
   /**
    * @var integer Id
    *
    * @Id @Column(type="integer")
    * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $schId
     *
     * @Column(name="schId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $schId;

    /**
     * @var integer $stdId
     *
     * @Column(name="stdId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $stdId;


    /**
     * @var integer $trainerPsnId
     *
     * @Column(name="trainerPsnId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $trainerPsnId;

    /**
     * @var boolean $isLegacy
     *
     * @Column(name="isLegacy", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $isLegacy;

    /**
     * @var float $charge
     *
     * @Column(name="charge", type="float", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $charge;

    /**
     * @var float $trainerPay
     *
     * @Column(name="trainerPay", type="float", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $trainerPay;

    /**
     * @var integer $modeId
     *
     * @Column(name="modeId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $modeId;

    /**
     * @var text $notes
     *
     * @Column(name="notes", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * @var string $twitterNote
     *
     * @Column(name="twitterNote", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $twitterNote;

    // ASSOCIATIONS
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Schedule", inversedBy="session")
     * @JoinColumn(name="schId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $schedule;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="SnSoapeNotes", mappedBy="session")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="snId")
     */
    protected $soapeNote;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Students")
     * @JoinColumn(name="stdId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $student;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Personnel", inversedBy="sessions")
     * @JoinColumn(name="trainerPsnId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $trainer;

    // Getters and Setters
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSchId()
    {
        return $this->schId;
    }

    public function setSchId($schId)
    {
        $this->schId = $schId;
    }

    public function getStdId()
    {
        return $this->stdId;
    }

    public function setStdId($stdId)
    {
        $this->stdId = $stdId;
    }

    public function getTrainerPsnId()
    {
        return $this->trainerPsnId;
    }

    public function setTrainerPsnId($trainerPsnId)
    {
        $this->stdId = $trainerPsnId;
    }

    public function getIsLegacy()
    {
        return $this->isLegacy;
    }

    public function setIsLegacy($isLegacy)
    {
        $this->isLegacy = $isLegacy;
    }

    public function getCharge()
    {
        return $this->charge;
    }

    public function setCharge($charge)
    {
        $this->charge = $charge;
    }

    public function getTrainerPay()
    {
        return $this->trainerPay;
    }

    public function setTrainerPay($trainerPay)
    {
        $this->trainerPay = $trainerPay;
    }

    public function getModeId()
    {
        return $this->modeId;
    }

    public function setModeId($modeId)
    {
        $this->modeId = $modeId;
    }

    public function getNotes()
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }

    public function setNotes($notes)
    {
        $this->notes = $notes;
    }

    public function getTwitterNote()
    {
        return $this->twitterNote;
    }

    public function setTwitterNote($twitterNote)
    {
        $this->twitterNote = $twitterNote;
    }

    // Foreign Data

    public function getSchedule()
    {
        return $this->schedule;
    }

    public function getStudent()
    {
        return $this->student;
    }
    public function getTrainer()
    {
        return $this->trainer;
    }

    public function getSoapeNote()
    {
        return $this->soapeNote;
    }
}
```

SnSoapeNotes:

```
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * SnSoapeNotes
 *
 * @Table(name="SnSoapeNotes")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\SnSoapeNotes")
 */
class SnSoapeNotes
{

    /**
    * @var integer Id
    *
    * @Id @Column(type="integer")
    * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;



    /**
     * @var integer $mental
     *
     * @Column(name="mental", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $mental;

    /**
     * @var integer $physical
     *
     * @Column(name="physical", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $physical;

    /**
     * @var text $subjective
     *
     * @Column(name="subjective", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $subjective;

    /**
     * @var text $objective
     *
     * @Column(name="objective", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $objective;

    /**
     * @var text $plan
     *
     * @Column(name="plan", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $plan;

    /**
     * @var text $action
     *
     * @Column(name="action", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $action;

    /**
     * @var text $education
     *
     * @Column(name="education", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $education;

    /**
     * @var text $warning
     *
     * @Column(name="warning", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
private $warning;

/**
 * @var text $incident
 *
 * @Column(name="incident", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $incident;

/**
 * @var text $technical
 *
 * @Column(name="technical", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $technical;

// ASSOCIATIONS
/**
 * @Var Sessions $sessions
 * 
 * @Column(name="snId", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Sessions", inversedBy="soapeNote")
 * @JoinColumn(name="snId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $sessions;

// Getters and Setters
public function getSnId()
{
    return $this->snId;
}

public function setSnId($snId)
{
    $this->snId = $snId;
}

public function getMental()
{
    return $this->mental;
}

public function setMental($mental)
{
    $this->mental = $mental;
}

public function getPhysical()
{
    return $this->physical;
}

public function setPhysical($physical)
{
    $this->physical = $physical;
}

public function getSubjective()
{
    return $this->subjective;
}

public function setSubjective($subjective)
{
    $this->subjective = $subjective;
}

public function getObjective()
{
    return $this->objective;
}

public function setObjective($objective)
{
    $this->objective = $objective;
}

public function getPlan()
{
    return $this->plan;
}

public function setPlan($plan)
{
    $this->plan = $plan;
}

public function getAction()
{
    return $this->action;
}

public function setAction($action)
{
    $this->action = $action;
}

public function getEducation()
{
    return $this->education;
}

public function setEducation($education)
{
    $this->education = $education;
}

public function getWarning()
{
    return $this->warning;
}

public function setWarning($warning)
{
    $this->warning = $warning;
}

public function getIncident()
{
    return $this->incident;
}

public function setIncident($incident)
{
    $this->incident = $incident;
}

public function getTechnical()
{
    return $this->technical;
}

public function setTechnical($technical)
{
    $this->technical = $technical;
}

public function getSession()
{
    return $this->session;

}

// A quick way to make sure the soape note has been completed.
// Note that objective is left out here because it can be
// filled out beforehand
public function getIsComplete()
{
    return !empty($this->subjective)
        && !empty($this->action)
        && !empty($this->plan)
        && !empty($this->education);
}
```

}

When calling $em->getRepository('Entities\Sessions')->findOneBy('id'), everything works fine--I get the session and its accompanying SOAPE note. Ditto for other associated tables' data.

But now I am trying to write a custom repository to get the notes prior to this session. The function is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

/**
 * Sessions
 */
class Sessions extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getPastSoapeNotes($params) {
        $studentId = $params['studentId'];
        $latestSession = $params['snDatetime'] ?: date('Y-m-d H:i');

        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('n.subjective, n.objective, n.plan, n.action, n.education')
        ->from('Entities\Sessions', 'sn')
        ->innerJoin('sn.Entities\SnSoapeNotes', 'n');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

When I call this, I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 126 near 'n': Error: Class Entities\Sessions has no association named Entities\SnSoapeNotes
```

I have also tried using the "mappedBy" and "inersedBy" annotations in every possible combination, but to no avail; Doctrine can't seem to find the association. I am at a complete loss as to what is going on.

Comment: where is your Sessions entity defined?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong. In the join statement, I used 'sn.Entities\SnSoapeNotes' when I should have used just 'soapeNote', which is the **property** in the Sessions class, not the table name itself.